# Where should i keep my log4j2.properties file?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, log4j, rest-assured

I  have created all my test cases under \src\test\java\TestCases. Have created a resources folder under \src\test\resources and kept **log4j2.properties** file there.

Please refer the below screenshot. [image]

But when ever I am running my tests I am getting below warning and logs are not getting printed.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I tried PropertyConfigurator.configure() it is working.

Wanted to check how can i do without PropertyConfigurator what should be the correct path of my log4j file.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set the actual path at the start of your method to use the path where log4j2 properties file is

System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", System.getProperty("user.dir") +
"\src\test\resources\log4j2.properties");